# How to Get Last Known Location in Fragment Class?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to create a location-aware app and I followed various tutorials on youtube.
I stumbled upon this [Getting Last Known Location Tutorial by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) but it seems that it's for Activity class. Can't find any tutorials about it that uses Fragment class.

I want to show a marker on current location when the Fragment View is created.

Here's my code:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.tugboat.tugboat.R;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);//when you already implement OnMapReadyCallback in your fragment
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have to accept to enjoy all app's services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you really need to ask how to move something from an Activity to a Fragment class when you're given code from the fragment, you need to try to understand what you're coding more and use tutorials a LOT less.  Activities and Fragments aren't magic, they're just Java classes.

Comment: Probably you move your logic to Service and onLocationChange, use localbroadcast event to publish locations and handle it in your fragment.